# STATUS_CODE_ERROR when upgrade Xcode from App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I try to upgrade Xcode to support IOS 8.2 as instructed by Auto-update from App Store.

The STATUS_CODE_ERROR at login Username and Password.

I am sure my password is right (tested with web login to the iTunes.apple.com
 [image]

Any work around ?

Comment: Correct @T.Kul i am also facing same problem. As well i am not able to login to iTunes Connect.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6868907

Comment: I think it  look like Apple App Store outage. If so it should be ok sometime later. Just wait then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming or the tools used to program. It's just the app store server being down and is a temporary issue.

Comment: If you're testing on an iOS8.2 device and haven't yet updated to XCode 6.2 your code won't run so, indirectly, it does affect XCode. There is no workaround I can think of other than to use the simulator until the app store comes back to life.

Comment: My test work around after I knew some area could work I would try to VPN to that region e.g.: US. But for me really I need to upgrade because error in Ruby that required Xcode command line upgrade. However I don't known yet what it could cause that error until I could rule out by upgrade Xcode.

Comment: I believed my question is about software tools.
Rule to  judge on the question not from the answer unless otherwise we would not be judge any question until we get the right answer.
It's doesn't make sense for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no workaround as it is a problem at Apple's infrastructure.
You find articles about this by web search or people complaining on twitter etc. Example:

http://www.neowin.net/news/apple-services-including-app-store-hit-by-major-worldwide-outage

Useful site for checking services of big companies as it is fed by user complaints: https://downdetector.com/

P.S.: Apple's https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ currently does NOT show any failures… :-/

Comment: Now https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ updated, admitting still problems:

All users are affected
Customers may be unable to make purchases from the App Store, iTunes Store, iBooks Store, or Mac App Store.

Comment: Now 4 red services: "Customers may be unable to make purchases from the App Store, iTunes Store, iBooks Store, or Mac App Store."

Answer (score 0):

Just saw on Apple's page https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ that they mention the problem: "iCloud Account & Sign In - All users were affected Users may have been unable to sign in.". The wording indicates that Apple considers the problem as resolved (however, still no login...).